# How do I differentiate between Django messages in templates while using nested modals?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, bootstrap-4

So, I've been racking my brain on this for 2 days now. Any help would be awesome!

At the heart of my issue, I believe, is that I have nested modals and a custom bootstrap form in both: the first for login, and the second for signup. Let's assume in one case I want to do all my validations server-side, and possibly get full control over each of the error validation messages, as well as how and where they should appear respective to their input. How do I do that using django.contrib.messages?

** If I could use some of Bootstrap 4's built-in methods for validation as a first line of defense, or **data-validate-on-blur** to work like how it does with Zurb Foundation's Abide, even better.

### Template tags in each base.html modal:

```
{% if messages %}
    <div class='container-fluid bg-white mt-5 pt-5 pl-4 mb-4'>
        {% for message in messages %}
            <p class="small font-poller text-danger">{{ message }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

---

### Trials and tribulations thus far:

As it stands, and with the various work-arounds I've found on Stack Overflow, i.e. using jQuery to toggle the modal (not the prettiest as it reloads the page), the best I've been able to do still bleeds my messages in between modals and/or my redirect views.

I've read threads on how to clear Django messages, and thought that might be a fix, so if after I close a modal or open a new modal, the messages essentially are cleared out until the form is submitted once again. In other words, the login error messages are unique to the login modal when its form's submit button is pressed, and signup error messages are unique to the signup modal when its form's submit button is pressed.

Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to use a view (views.py), to successfully achieve this. The thought comes to mind that since because I'm using modals to trigger that event, I would have to use jQuery for that, but I have failed on that front also. I'm really hoping there is a more straight-forward solution to this.

Thanks in advance,

Dev

---

PS - my snippets:

### views.py

```
def signup(request):
    signup_errors = User.objects.validation(request.POST, 'register')
    if len(signup_errors):
        for error in signup_errors.values():
            messages.error(request, error)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        new_user = User.objects.create(
            first_name      = request.POST['first_name'],
            last_name       = request.POST['last_name'],
            dob             = request.POST['dob'],
            phone           = request.POST['phone'],
            address         = request.POST['address'],
            city            = request.POST['city'],
            state           = request.POST['state'],
            zipcode         = request.POST['zipcode'],
            email           = request.POST['email'],
            password        = 
bcrypt.hashpw(request.POST['password'].encode(), bcrypt.gensalt()))
        request.session['first_name'] = new_user.first_name
        request.session['id']   = new_user.id
        messages.info(request, 'You have successfully submitted your 
information.')
        return redirect('/menu')


def login(request):
    login_errors = User.objects.validation(request.POST, 'login')
    if len(login_errors):
        for error in login_errors.values():
            messages.error(request, error)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        current_user = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
        request.session['first_name']   = current_user.first_name
        request.session['id']           = current_user.id
        messages.info(request, 'You have successfully logged in.')
        return redirect('/menu')
```

### models.py

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def validation(self, postData, error_validation):
        errors = {}
        if error_validation == 'register':
            if not NAME_REGEX.match(postData['first_name']):
                errors['first_name'] = "First name can only contain 
letters!"
            if len(postData['last_name']) < 1:
                errors['last_name'] = "Last name cannot be blank."
            if not NAME_REGEX.match(postData['last_name']):
                errors['last_name'] = "Last name can only contain letters!"
        if error_validation == 'login':
            user = User.objects.filter(email=postData['email'])
            if not user:
                errors['user_login'] = "No account with that email in 
our system."
            elif not bcrypt.checkpw(postData['password'].encode(), 
user[0].password.encode()):
                errors['password_login'] = "Invalid email and/or 
password!"
        return errors
```

### login modal in base.html

```
<div class="modal fade text-dark" id="loginModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content font-paytone">
            <div class="modal-header shadow p-3 bg_primary rounded">
                <h5 class="modal-title font-poller text-light text_shadow_success2" id="loginModal">Login <i class="fa fa-user text-center ml-1"></i></h5>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form id="login-form" action="{% url 'ecommerce_app:login' %}" method="POST" novalidate>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>                          
                    <input id="login-form-submit-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block border bg_primary btn_login" value="Log In">
                </form>

                <p class="pt-2 font-passion">Don't have an account? Sign up below!</p>
                <button id="login-form-signup-btn" class="btn btn-info btn-block border" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal">Sign Up</button>
            </div>

            {% if messages %}
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class='container-fluid bg-white'>
                        {% for message in messages %}
                            <p class="small font-poller text-danger">{{ message }}</p>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### register modal in base.html

```
<div class="modal fade text-dark" id="registerModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content font-paytone">
            <div class="modal-header shadow p-3 bg_primary rounded">
                <h5 class="modal-title font-poller text-light text_shadow_info" id="registerModal">Sign Me Up! <i class="fa fa-user-plus ml-1"></i></h5>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id='signup-form' action="/signup/" method="POST" novalidate>
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
                            <input type="date" name="dob" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="phone">Phone #</label>
                            <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="address">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Street" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-7">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="City" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" placeholder="State" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                              <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{5}" name="zipcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <!-- <label for="password">Password</label> -->
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <!-- <label for="confirm">Confirm Password</label> -->
                            <input type="password" name="confirm" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block font-fredoka">Register</button>
                        {% if messages %}
                            <div class='container-fluid bg-white mt-5 pt-5 pl-4 mb-4'>
                                {% for message in messages %}
                                    <p class="small font-poller text-danger">{{ message }}</p>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PSS - if I can help to clarify anything else please let me know**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I solved my own problem and am somehow compelled to share with others the solution as I think I actually lost sleep over this one. Anyway, I'm not really sure if this is what Django message class '**extra_tags**' attribute was originally intended for, but for all intents and purposes it is a clean fix and allows me control over both server-side and client validation messages.

---

First, I assign **extra_tags** to 'register' and 'login' respectively when I create and append each message instance:

### views.py

```
def signup(request):
    errors = User.objects.validation(request.POST, 'register')
    if len(errors):
        for error in errors.values():
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, error, extra_tags="register")
        return redirect('/')

def login(request):
    errors = User.objects.validation(request.POST, 'login')
    if len(errors):
        for error in errors.values():
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, error, extra_tags="login")
        return redirect('/')
```

---

I check to see if there are messages, then iterate through them, checking if the tag is 'register' (or 'login'), and if so, render some text, if not, don't render anything.

### base.html

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {% if 'register' in message.tags %}
            <p class="small font-poller text-danger registration_error_message">{{ message }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

---

Last but not least, after you submit the form through either modal, you will need to reload the modal with the aforementioned error (or success) messages. To have each modal show its respective messages you will have to differentiate and then toggle to open each one the same way I did using **template_tags** in the base.html, only this time using a little jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                {% if 'login' in message.tags %}
                    $('#loginModal').modal('toggle');
                {% elif 'register' in message.tags %}
                    $('#registerModal').modal('toggle');
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    });
</script>
```